# Check if path along triangular shapefile possible

Tags: shapefile, distance, path

I have a problem I came across but don't know how to solve it. I have a triangular shapefile of a river with one attribute value being the water depth. The idea is to find out if fish are able to swim from one end of the river to the other end. The condition that is required is, that the fish always has a water depth of at least 30cm along the path. 
My solution was to first delete all the fields with water depth of less than 30cm. The next step I wanted to do then was to check if there is a path possible possible from point A to point B without a gap along the path. however I did not find out how to do this. Any idea on how to solve this? Or any better way on how to approach this problem?

Comment: What's a "triangular shapefile"? Is it just one triangle? Or is it a river that is finely divided into triangular polygons showing the depth? Can you show a map of this?

Comment: Why are you even asking this question, when it rains the river depth will increase and the river will be passable. Is your river in some sort of desert scenario or has some sort of controlling factor limiting water supply? I would question the ecological premise behind this question. Movement of fish are far more likely to be hindered by barriers put in by man than low flow conditions.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a least cost path analysis. Your data would need to be converted to raster format though.